# how to check Is2faEnabled in identity server while using connect/token for mobile login?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, identityserver3, asp.net-authorization, identityserver5

In my project, Identity Server is already implemented for web, and it's functioning well, including 2-Factor Authentication (2-FA). Currently, when logging in from a mobile device, we make a call to:`domain/connect/token`

This endpoint returns the response

```
access_token: String,
expires_in: Int,
refresh_token: String,
scope: String,
token_type: String
```

and we use it for authentication, allowing the user to access our dashboard. Now, we've made the decision to implement 2-FA for mobile screens as well. How can we achieve this using `connect/token` or any other method without creating a custom API for login? Does Identity Server provide a specific URL or mechanism through which we can determine whether 2-FA is enabled for a given user and the further proceedings?